# How does `is` really work with primitive types in python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, spaces, primitive

My understanding is that all **primitive** types are *referentially* equal if they are equal in *value*.

With integers, this seems to be the case shown from the following example:

```
v1 = 2
v2 = 2
v1 is v2 # prints True
```

With booleans, this also seems to be the case shown from the following example:

```
v1 = False
v2 = False
v1 is v2 # prints True
```

With strings, it starts to get a little confusing. The following example follows the procedure:

```
v1 = 'testtest'
v2 = 'testtest'
v1 is v2 # prints True
```

However, as soon as I add a space to the string, it fails:

```
v1 = 'test test'
v2 = 'test test'
v1 is v2 # prints False
```

With floats, the pattern just doesn't exist:

```
v1 = 2.0
v2 = 2.0
v1 is v2 # prints False
```

Why do strings follow the rule except when spaces are added? Why do floats not follow the rule at all? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "My understanding is that all primitive types are referentially equal if they are equal in value." - not sure where you got that idea, but your tests clearly show it's false.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: Python doesn't even have a concept of "primitive" types, anyway. This isn't Java.

Comment: TL;DR: certain small values are internally cached, *interned*. That's an optimisation detail you shouldn't worry about much. Simply never use `is` in this way, it's not supposed to be used for these operations.

Answer (score 0):

*With integers, this seems to be the case shown from the following example:*

```
v1 = 2
v2 = 2
v1 is v2 # prints True
```

You are spoiled by implementation detail which made *certain* integers to behave that way, consider counter-example:

```
t1 = 1000000
t2 = 1000000
print(t1 is t2)  # False
```